# Select foreign key (group) where is the biggest match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have three tables **group_sentences**, **group_sentences_attributes** and **group_senteces_categories**.

I have an attributes array which I am using in query with `IN` (after implode).

Then I have one category ID because they are stored recursively, so no need for an array.

**I need to select one group number where is the biggest match for $attributesArray and of course category too.**

Here is table group_sentences_attributes

```
+-----+-------+-----------+
| id  | group | attribute |
+-----+-------+-----------+
|  1  |   1   |   3564    |
|  2  |   1   |   3687    |
|  3  |   1   |   3689    |
|  4  |   2   |   3687    |
|  5  |   2   |   3564    |
+-----+-------+-----------+
```

Here is group_sentences_category

```
+-----+-------+----------+
| id  | group | category |
+-----+-------+----------+
|  1  |   1   |   1564   |
|  2  |   1   |   1221   |
|  3  |   1   |   1756   |
|  4  |   2   |   1358   |
|  5  |   2   |   1125   |
+-----+-------+----------+
```

Here is my query, but I am afraid that it won't do the job done.

```
SELECT group_categories.group
FROM group_categories, group_attributes 
WHERE group_categories.category = '$category'
    AND group_attributes.attribute IN ($attributesArray)
GROUP BY group_categories.group
ORDER BY count(group_attributes.attribute)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the table in your query do not match the tables in the question.  I am guessing they are simply missing the "sentence".  Then, you have no `join` clause.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

`group` is a lousy name for a column, because it is a keyword in SQL.  The following may be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT gc.groupid
FROM group_sentences_attributes sa JOIN
     group_sentences_category sc
     ON sa.groupid = sc.groupid
WHERE sc.category = '$category' AND
      sa.attribute IN ($attributesArray)
GROUP BY sa.groupid
ORDER BY count(sa.attribute);
```

If you only want one row, then add `LIMIT 1` to the end.